# JavaScript Keyboard repeat delay problems

Tags: javascript, game-development

I would like to create game controlled by wasd keys but it doesn't work as i thought. At any movement it make at first small step and then it's repeating movement without delay. Here's the code:

```
var Player = document.getElementById("Player");
const SpeedX = 35;
const SpeedY = 20;
var x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(Player).marginLeft);
var y = parseInt(getComputedStyle(Player).marginTop); 

var keysPressed = {};

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        keysPressed[e.key] = true;

        if(e.key == 'w') {
        if(y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y -= SpeedY;
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
            console.log(y);
        } else if(y == 950) Player.style.marginTop = (y -= SpeedY) + "px";
    }
        if(e.key == 'a') {
        if(x > -5 && x < 1780) {
            x -= SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            console.log(x);
        } else if(x == 1780) Player.style.marginLeft = (x -= SpeedX) + "px";
    }
        if(e.key == 's') {
        if(y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y += SpeedY;
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
            console.log(y);
        } else if(y == 30) Player.style.marginTop = (y += SpeedY) + "px";
    }
        if(e.key == 'd') {
        if(x > -5 && x < 1780) {
            x += SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            console.log(x);
        } else if(x == -5) Player.style.marginLeft = (x += SpeedX) + "px";
    }
        if(e.key == 'w' && keysPressed['a']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y -= SpeedY;
            x -= SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 'w' && keysPressed['d']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y -= SpeedY;
            x += SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 's' && keysPressed['a']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y += SpeedY;
            x -= SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 's' && keysPressed['d']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y += SpeedY;
            x += SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 'a' && keysPressed['w']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y -= SpeedY;
            x -= SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 'd' && keysPressed['w']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y -= SpeedY;
            x += SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 'a' && keysPressed['s']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y += SpeedY;
            x -= SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
        if(e.key == 'd' && keysPressed['s']) {
            if(x > -5 && x < 1780 && y > 30 && y < 950) {
            y += SpeedY;
            x += SpeedX;
            Player.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            Player.style.marginTop = y + "px";
        }}
    })

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    delete keysPressed[event.key];
});
```

It looks not so nice when it's not moving smoothly. Please Help

I've looked for some solutions in browser but i can't find anything useful at my case

Comment: You're looking for how to "debounce" the key input. You should be able to find _loads_ of answers and web pages that talk about how to do that using that term.

Comment: You could also use some sort of ticker that would loop constantly and place all of your movement logic there. Then you would have `keydown` and `keyup` events only taking care of setting and unsetting values in the `keysPressed` list. You would possibly open a whole new can of worms with asynchronous execution then though.

Comment: The solution should be very simple: instead of setting `y` with the keypresses directly, you should only adjust `yspeed` when a key is pressed. Then, in EVERY frame of your game (regardless if a key was pressed) you adjust the characters `y` with the `yspeed`. The yspeed should be 0 if no key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be your solution.

```
var playerMoving;
var keyPressed = {};

function keyDown(e) {
  //Here you check if the last key pressed has changed
  //so that we will clear the interval
  if (e.which !== keyPressed[e.key]) {
    if (playerMoving) {
      clearInterval(playerMoving);
      playerMoving = null;
    }
  }

  //here we are remembering the last keypress
  keyPressed[e.key] = e.which;
  if (!playerMoving) {
    //creating the interval that will make your player move
    playerMoving = setInterval(() => {
      document.body.innerHTML += "+";
      //instead of the line above create a function with all your logic that you will call
    }, 10);
  }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

//here removing the interval when the user is not pressing a key anymore
window.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  clearInterval(playerMoving);
  playerMoving = null;
});
```

The working demo: https://codepen.io/eli-ott/pen/OJBZEPO

It is I think what you want to achieve in a good way.

I tried commenting the code as much as I could to make it more understandable.

*The pen is inspired from this question (was revisited to fit your code/question) : [Cross-browser way to get automatically repeating keydown events when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027818/cross-browser-way-to-get-automatically-repeating-keydown-events-when-key-is-held)*

Comment: I mean prevent first single move before constantly repeating

Comment: @kaskas try `function keyDown(e){ let first = true if (e.repeat && first === true){ ... }}`

Comment: Ok, it's better but how to delete that delat before every move?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448981/remove-keydown-delay-in-javascript ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's what i'm looking for

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, I might be your solution :)

Comment: Now it movs without delay but it go to the edge of the screen nearly instanty, maybe i pasted something bad. I have to paste it where the coment write to do so?

Comment: You need to create a function with all your player logic in it, like where you check which key is pressed etc. And call that function where the comment is. And if the delay is too short, you just have to increase the ```setInterval()``` delay